# What foods can you cook by directly placing them into a fire?

Tags: food, camp-fire-cooking

Sometimes I do not want to bother wish dishes. The other day, I took a yellow pepper, and placed into a wood fire I had going, and left it there for a good 5 minutes while I prepared a curry. I pulled it out, peeled the skin, threw it into the curry, and enjoyed it well.

I am curious if there is any other food you can do this with? Something that you can just stick directly into a fire without having to worry too much about.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *placing into fire*? If you throw a pepper **in** a fire, it should burn rather quickly. Do you mean the glow which isn't burning anymore?

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace Good question. Tossing it into the glow; it would be hard to have a piece of food below a flame from a fire without you actively trying to suspend it there.

Comment: corn on the cobbbbb in husk...A personal favourite!

Comment: If you don't want to wash dishes while camping, use freezer bag cooking. This will also have the side benefit of preventing diarrhea caused by bad potty hygiene and hand-to-mouth contamination from your hiking partners.

Comment: All of them if you don't mind crispy outside and frozen centers :-)

Comment: Roasted Potatoes tastes so good.

Comment: Egg. An onion can be cut in half and the center pulled out to make a bowl. Break an egg or two into the onion bowl and place in fire. Use a stick with a Y at the end to put the food in and out. When cooked the outer layer may be removed to reveal cooked onion and egg.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another one would be [Damper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damper_(food)), an Australian bush bread traditionally cooked in the hot ashes of a dying fire, with or without tin-foil (just don’t eat the crust). It has a pretty delicious smokey taste and is fun to make with the kids.

I won’t suggest a particular recipe because there are so many variations. The core is just flour, baking soda, salt, and water, and then it can be varied with milk, honey or golden syrup, beer, herbs, cheese, olive oil, tea… whatever you happen to have.

[image: damper being cooked in coals]

Comment: Great idea! A variation on this is to wrap the dough around a stick and just bake it over the open flames. We used to call this [snake bread](http://www.spielmobil-uster.ch/attachments/Image/Schlangenbrot.jpg), and kids absolutely love it.

Comment: bannock is the Canadian name for it. if you cook it on a stick you can fill the hole with jam.

Comment: @KateGregory Bannock is cooked on a stick, and actually does not use baking soda... or at least that is how it was taught to us at outdoor school (I'm from Vancouver).

Answer (score 30):

Basically tin foil is your friend!

Even though you could also place some of these foods directly on the embers, if you're willing to carry some tin foil and do a little bit of preparation, you can create some awesome meals on a campfire.

### Potatoes

[image: Potato]

<sup>Image by [Ryan Dickey](https://flic.kr/p/5wMrnW)</sup>

- Slice them open unpeeled and fill them with **cream cheese**
- Season with salt, chives, garlic, rosemary, thyme
- Wrap tightly in tin foil and place on hot embers for about 25-40 minutes, depending on size

---

### Fish

[image: Fish]

<sup>Image by [jypsygen](https://flic.kr/p/dPJG4D)</sup>

- Gut and clean the fish, season with salt and pepper
- Slice open lengthwise, and fill with lemon slices and spring onion rings
- Add some fresh herbs and spices: Parsley, coriander, garlic, cumin, chilli flakes
- Wrap in tin foil and place it on hot embers with the opening facing up so it doesn't dry out

---

### Mushrooms

[image: Grilled Mushrooms]

<sup>Image by [Richard Lee](https://flic.kr/p/dFmqFE)</sup>

- Get some large mushrooms - large Portobello mushrooms work well
- Remove the stem and cut out some of the flesh to create a large opening
- Very lightly salt the inside and fill with cream cheese with some finely chopped chives mixed in
- Wrap in tin foil and place on hot embers - only takes a couple minutes

---

### Chocolate bananas

[image: Chocolate Bananas]

<sup>Image by [Mike](https://flic.kr/p/5e2WYd)</sup>

- Cut a lengthwise slit in the bananas (can be done with or without peeling them)
- Fill the bananas with chocolate chips or small pieces, and possibly other goodies like marshmallows or graham cracker crumbs
- Wrap in tin foil and place on hot embers for a couple minutes

Comment: +1 Great answer. Just one addition... we do the bananas with a splash of rum so if you have it with you or do them on a bbq... :)

Comment: Wow this picture of the choco banana!!! Awesome, I give it a 9+ banana score!

Comment: Potatoes work well without tinfoil. The outer layer becomes a burnt black crust which functions exactly like tinfoil. You can then slice it open and eat the inner part with a spoon. The crust is strong enough that you don't have to worry about piercing it from the inside and accidentally eating it.

Comment: Also any starchy or root vegetable: yam, kumara, parsnip.

Comment: @Philipp Some people like eating the skins, though!

Answer (score 9):

[image: Mielies (bbq corn)]

Picture via Google from [Our South African barbecue, a way of life](http://www.south-africa-tours-and-travel.com/south-african-barbecue.html)

Ideally you actually bbq by smearing butter on them first then grilling. The outside caramelizes into golden to just short of black. Some black is fine too, it all tastes so much better than boiled or in foil.

If you lack a grill then desperate measures include chucking it in the ashes (with tin foil or still in husk), or propping it up against some wood in the flames. If you have a long stick like thing you can hand roast it (like kebab skewers or something similar).

Answer (score 9):

If you use wood chunk charcoal, skirt steak is awesome cooked right on the coals. Credit: Alton Brown, [How to Cook Steak on Coals (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5y2voEWJ6U).

[image: How to Cook Steak on Coals]

Answer (score 7):

The best tasting dish I personally ate that was cooked over fire is [mandi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandi_%28food%29). Image Credit: Wikipedia.

[image: From Wikipedia]

> Mandi is usually made from rice (basmati), meat (lamb or chicken), and
>   a mixture of spices. The meat used is usually a young and small sized
>   lamb to enhance the taste further. The main thing which differentiates
>   mandi is that the meat is cooked in the tandoor (taboon in Hadhrami),
>   which is a special kind of oven. **The tandoor is usually a hole dug in
>   the ground and covered inside by clay. To cook mandi, dry wood is
>   placed in the tandoor and burned to generate a lot of heat turning
>   into charcoal. Then the meat is suspended inside the tandoor without
>   touching the charcoal. After that, the whole tandoor is closed without
>   letting any of the smoke outside. Raisins and pine nuts can be added
>   to the rice as per one's taste.**
>
> Mandi serves as the main dish considered served during special events,
>   such as weddings and feasts.

Answer (score 3):

Once I did bread buns stuffed with sweet cottage cheese, some cream and raisins, wrapped up in tin foil and placed in the embers for some 10 minutes.

Similar: cut out the middle of an apple, fill it with diced nuts, raisins, sugar, cinnamon.

Other one: dice any juicy vegetable (courgette, eggplant, onions, mushrooms, tomatoes, paprikas), apply some spices (I used oregano, pepper and salt), wrap in tin foil, cook it for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Something we always did as scouts was to put cut up potatoes, vegetables, and sausage into a tin foil bowl and stick it in the fire. I always remember them cooking very well and they were also very hearty. Also, very little setup/cleanup; which I am always for!

Breakfast can also be done in a foil bowl, just put scrambled eggs, sausage, green onions, cheese, and whatever else into a bowl and stick that into the fire for a nice crustless Quiche.

But I'm no chef, so I don't really have anything else per se but some general advice: if it's a food item that does not need much attention, then it will probably work in a fire.

***Pro Tip:*** Double wrap it if you can, you don't want the foil taring and getting ash all in your food!

***Other Good Recipes:*** Anything you can stick a stick through works as well (hot dogs, marshmallows, etc.) In a completely separate category, making peach cobbler in a dutch oven is always a good camping desert.

Answer (score 3):

One of my favourites is [breadfruit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_fruit), which I acquired a taste for while living in Jamaica.  They apparently grow all over Southeast Asia and the Pacific too. In Jamaica they grow wild practically everywhere (there is a peak season when they end up littering the ground in places), making them a staple bush food. I've seen them occasionally in the supermarket in North America; you can also cook them whole in a barbecue or an oven.

Here's what they look like fresh:

[image]

And after roasting in a fire for 45-60 minutes:

[image]

The outer rind can be completely charred black; this one perhaps is a bit under done.  Inside, there's a mild tasting, wonderfully soft textured (hence the "bread", I would guess) carb rich meat:

[image]

They are the size of small melons. If only the forests here had stuff like this!  I might not have to take any food hiking at all.  If you are ever anywhere where they have this, try it.  It's also prepared various other ways and served with all kinds of stuff, as it's complementary to most things (again, like bread) and can absorb sauce.  Mmmm.

Comment: Breadfruit isn't actually native to Jamaica. [The Bounty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutiny_on_the_Bounty) went on an expedition to bring breadfruit back to Jamaica that didn't turn out so well.

Answer (score 3):

Pumpkins and the like. The skin will protect it, and will peel off nicely once burnt to a crisp. After; Peel the skin off, scoop out the middle, and eat it nice and soft like a potato, or make a pumpkin pie~